# Assigning to a subset of a Dataframe (with a selection or other method) in python Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

In Pandas I can do the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
{   
    "era": ["01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "10"],
    "pred1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6],
    "pred2": [2,4,5,6,7,8],
    "pred3": [3,5,6,8,9,1],
    "something_else": [5,4,3,67,5,4],
})
pred_cols = ["pred1", "pred2", "pred3"]
ERA_COL = "era"
DOWNSAMPLE_CROSS_VAL = 10

test_split = ['01', '02', '10']
test_split_index = data[ERA_COL].isin(test_split)
downsampled_train_split_index = train_split_index[test_split_index].index[::DOWNSAMPLE_CROSS_VAL]

data.loc[test_split_index, "pred1"] = somefunction()["another_column"]
```

How can I achieve the same in Polars? I tried to do some `data.filter(****) = somefunction()["another_column"]`, but the `filter` output is not assignable with Polars.

Comment: what's `data`? can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: Can't really come up for a simple example to `somefunction`, but I reworked the rest of the example.

Comment: thanks - I'll try to post an answer if you come up with an example `somefunction`

Comment: Is your some_function() an ML algorithm out of sklearn and it uses global variables instead of taking parameters and it returns a pandas DF?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can help.  It would appear that what you want to accomplish is to replace a subset/filtered portion of a column with values derived from other one or more other columns.

For example, if you are attempting to accomplish this:

```py
ERA_COL = "era"

test_split = ["01", "02", "10"]
test_split_index = data[ERA_COL].isin(test_split)

data.loc[test_split_index, "pred1"] = -2 * data["pred3"]
print(data)
```

```
>>> print(data)
  era  pred1  pred2  pred3  something_else
0  01     -6      2      3               5
1  01    -10      4      5               4
2  02    -12      5      6               3
3  02    -16      6      8              67
4  03      5      7      9               5
5  10     -2      8      1               4
```

We would accomplish the above in Polars using a `when/then/otherwise` expression:

```py
(
    pl.from_pandas(data)
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col(ERA_COL).is_in(test_split))
        .then(-2 * pl.col('pred3'))
        .otherwise(pl.col('pred1'))
        .alias('pred1')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬────────────────┐
│ era ┆ pred1 ┆ pred2 ┆ pred3 ┆ something_else │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---            │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64            │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│ 01  ┆ -6    ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 5              │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 01  ┆ -10   ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 4              │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 02  ┆ -12   ┆ 5     ┆ 6     ┆ 3              │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 02  ┆ -16   ┆ 6     ┆ 8     ┆ 67             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 03  ┆ 5     ┆ 7     ┆ 9     ┆ 5              │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10  ┆ -2    ┆ 8     ┆ 1     ┆ 4              │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴────────────────┘
```

Is this what you were looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

A few things as general points.

1. polars syntax doesn't attempt to match that of pandas.
2. In polars, you can only assign a whole df, you can't assign part of a df.
3. polars doesn't use an internal index so there's no index to record

For your problem, assuming there isn't already a natural index, you'd want to make an explicit index.

```
pldata=pl.from_pandas(data).with_row_count(name='myindx)
```

then recording the index would be

```
test_split_index = pldata.filter(pl.col(ERA_COL).is_in(test_split)).select('myindx').to_series()
```

For your last bit on the final assignment, without knowing anything about somefunction my best guess is that you'd want to do that with a join.

Maybe something like:

```
pldata=pldata.join(
           pl.from_pandas(some_function()['another_column']) \
               .with_column(test_split_index.alias('myindex')),
            on='myindex')
```

Your `test_split_index` is actually a bool not the index whereas the above is the actual index so take that with a grain of salt.

All that being said, polars has free copies of data so rather than keeping track of index positions manually (as error prone as that can be), you can just make 2 new dfs since, under the hood, it just references the data, it doesn't make a physical copy of it.

Something like:

```
testdata=pldata.filter(pl.col(ERA_COL).is_in(test_split))

traindata=pldata.filter(~pl.col(ERA_COL).is_in(test_split))
```